# Getting error when absolute filepath is used

Tags: php

When I m using absolute dynamic file path its giving following error.

```
Warning: is_readable(): Unable to find the wrapper &quot;https&quot; - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
```

Comment: What is your code?  Just from the error, why are you including https in is_readable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

line to your `php.ini` file, or simply uncomment the line if it's already there.